# JavaScript CSS transition problem - rotating a carousel 360 degrees with cards flipping

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a carousel with cards that will hold content, viewed like you would view a book, I would like them to flip through the full array of cards, with the choice of going forwards and backwards.

The set up I have works if you continuously click on either the next or previous sections, if you click going the opposite way the cards will end up in the correct position, however the transitions are messed up.

Are you able to help me solve the transition issue?

I have attached a link to a CodePen

https://codepen.io/NPGB88/pen/GRxjJbq

```
enter code here
```

Comment: ig the problem is u r always adding the degrees to the position...for example the arousel_degs, plus_deg and minus_deg are always going up...to fix that one option is give to each card a index of position till reach 0, the restarts positions...

Comment: Sorry for the long reply, I wasn't 100% sure what you meant by this. However, I think I may have worked out what you were saying, see link - https://codepen.io/NPGB88/pen/GRxjrxv?editors=1111

Comment: I just need to work out how to get it to rotate / transition the correct way

Comment: na, still use your code...just fix the thing to reset the degrees...becouse for exemple 
going to change right? it increments the degrees that you have to change to get the next one....but if you look at the old code, what happens is that it increments degrees, that's why it gave more rotations... the problem is in the maximum degrees and minimus